# Dependency property type not respected

Tags: c#, wpf

Why can a dependency property with type XXX get a value of another type ?

Is the type of a dependency property just defined for the default value ?

**For example:**

Project structure:

[image: Project]

**User control code (CarControl):**

*XAML code:*

```
<UserControl x:Class="TypeOfDependencyProperty.Controls.CarControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Brand}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

*Code behind (C#):*

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TypeOfDependencyProperty.Controls
{
    public partial class CarControl : UserControl
    {
        #region Brand

        public static readonly DependencyProperty BrandProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Brand", typeof(string), typeof(CarControl),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((string)string.Empty));

        public string Brand
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(BrandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BrandProperty, value); }
        }

        #endregion

        public CarControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this dependency property `Brand` is of type `string` here.

**View code (CarView):**

*XAML code:*

```
<Page x:Class="TypeOfDependencyProperty.Views.CarView"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:TypeOfDependencyProperty.Controls"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
      Title="CarView">
    <Grid>
        <controls:CarControl Brand="{Binding Brand}"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

*Code behind (C#):*

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using TypeOfDependencyProperty.ViewModels;

namespace TypeOfDependencyProperty.Views
{
    public partial class CarView : Page
    {
        public CarView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new CarViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

**View model code (CarViewModel):**

```
namespace TypeOfDependencyProperty.ViewModels
{
    public class CarViewModel
    {
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public CarViewModel()
        {
            Brand = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; // Any value
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if I change the type from `string` to `List<XXX>` (or other) as below, it keeps working.

```
#region Brand

public static readonly DependencyProperty BrandProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Brand", typeof(List<double>), typeof(CarControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((List<double>)null));

public List<double>Brand
{
    get { return (List<double>)GetValue(BrandProperty); }
    set { SetValue(BrandProperty, value); }
}

#endregion
```

Of course, I obtain a following error in the output window but that still works ! The value is shown without failure when it's running.

> System.Windows.Data Error: 1 : Cannot create default converter to
>   perform 'one-way' conversions between types 'System.String' and
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Double]'. Consider using
>   Converter property of Binding. BindingExpression:Path=Brand;
>   DataItem='CarViewModel' (HashCode=14000148); target element is
>   'CarControl' (Name=''); target property is 'Brand' (type 'List`1')
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is
>   not valid for target property.; Value='Car brand'
>   BindingExpression:Path=Brand; DataItem='CarViewModel'
>   (HashCode=14000148); target element is 'CarControl' (Name=''); target
>   property is 'Brand' (type 'List`1')

Can somebody explain me? Is it a bug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Binding in

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Brand}"/>
```

binds directy to the Brand property in the view model. It does not use the `Brand` property of the control.

So it would even show the view model property value when you write

```
<controls:CarControl />
```

without binding the control's Brand property at all.

The correct usage of the control's property in the control's XAML would be this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Brand,
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

When you say 'get a value'

in:

> Why can a dependency property with type XXX get a value of another type ?

What you are asking about is really how a Binding is resolved.

The WPF framework resolves a binding and gets the actual current value.

When it is done resolving, the framework will try to 'set' the value for your dependency property, and only then will it check if the types are the same.

If they are not and no converter was supplied to the binding, it will throw this exception you added.

Comment: You are totally missing [TypeConverters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter?view=netframework-4.8), which are registered for many framework types, and allow assigning property values of types other than the declared one.

Comment: That's not what he asked about.

Comment: It's wrong what you say, that you always get a binding error when either the types don't match or there is no Binding Converter - because there are also TypeConverters. Besides that, your post does not answer the question. It is not asking why there is a binding error message (which seems obvious), but why the correct value is shown although there is a binding error. You may read my answer for an explanation.

Comment: Sorry about that, next time I try to help someone I'll include the entire Msft Docs page, hand typed.

Answer (score -1):

DependecyProperty type defines the type of data stored inside it.
You can bind to it only the same type of data. Or you can add a converter to binding. To do it you have to implement the interface [IValueConverter](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/).

But I don't understand your problem, want you to show entire list in a string? Or want you to create an item for each element of list?

In the second case I suggest you to use a ItemsControl and insert your custom control inside the [ItemTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate?view=netframework-4.8).

Finally you don't have to define default value every time, you can remove PropertyMetadata from DependecyProperty inizialization. And remember if you define it there it will be static and will change from others instances only  with base types. If you have a class I suggest you to use null and assign it in the class Costructor.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BrandProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Brand", typeof(List<double>), typeof(CarControl));
```

Comment: You are totally missing [TypeConverters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter?view=netframework-4.8), which are registered for many framework types, and allow assigning property values of types other than the declared one.